# Valgrind does not report returning pointer to stack allocated string

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm working with valgrind 3.12 for mips (mipsel) platform. I found that in the following example:

```
static char * return_stack_allocated_value(void)
{
   char x[100];
   snprintf(x,100,"Test test test");
   return x;
}

int main()
{
   char *bad;
   bad = return_stack_allocated_value();
   printf("Result: %s\n",bad);
}
```

valgrind does not report any error in this, although we can no longer use pointer to bad.

I run valgrind with the following options

```
--10-- Valgrind options:                                                                                                                                                                                
--10--    --main-stacksize=16777216                                                                                                                                                                     
--10--    --malloc-fill=0xab                                                                                                                                                                            
--10--    --free-fill=0x70                                                                                                                                                                              
--10--    --leak-check=full                                                                                                                                                                             
--10--    --leak-resolution=high                                                                                                                                                                        
--10--    --num-callers=50                                                                                                                                                                              
--10--    --trace-children=yes                                                                                                                                                                          
--10--    --track-origins=yes                                                                                                                                                                           
--10--    --log-file=/tmp/test_%p.log
```

Is it possible to spot such problems with valgrind? What options should be used?

Comment: What compiler are you using? What options are you passing to it when compiling? Because e.g. GCC should be able to detect it and issue a warning (with suitable options).

Comment: mipsel gcc. It does produce warning, but of course I'm trying to find problems in much larger program, not in the minimal example above.

Comment: And you don't get a warning for the larger program? Because if you *do* get a warning the compiler will tell you where so it should be easy to find such issues. It's also issues like this that makes many turn warnings into errors.

Comment: With `-Wall` option, gcc produces a warning : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9102ff69d556e5b6 and with `-Werror` transforms warning in error, which forces you to correct it to compile

Comment: Easy to say, difficult to follow;). No, the project will not build with -Werror, and this is not entirely my fault.

Comment: Absolutly not, I always realize professional project like that, and I avoid this kind of surprise. Warning aren't simple fancy of compiler, it's hint about bug prone software. And also, it answers your question, because it detects what you want to find (`-Werror` isn't mandatory, you can just parse output of compiler to find warning you want)

Comment: Most probably, compiler optimized out the return_stack_allocated_value function and main() is simply puts("Result: Test test test\n"). As valgrind operates on the binary produced, it does not report any problem, because it sees none...